# Doctrine2 inheretance and overloading

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Ive been stumped on the best way to implement Doctrine2 entities to archive the following.

Ill do my best to explain.

I want to have base rates for different tasks/jobs. Like job: do laundry with a rate of 50.00.
Then each customer can* override this job and rate. So customer: Wife, job: do laundry with a rate of 65.00.

So for each customer I would like to be able to do something like $customer->getJobRate(do laundry),
and if the customer have a specific implementation of that job it returns the specific rate, if no specific implementation is found if returns the default rate.

I may be thinking about this too hard, but all of the solutions I can come up with just seem 'ugly' to me.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way would be to have 3 entities: `Customer`, `Job`, `CustomerJobRate`. The pertinent properties would be:

```
Customer:
    jobRates (OneToMany => CustomerJobRate)

Job:
    defaultRate (float)

CustomerJobRate:
    job (ManyToOne => Job)
    customer (ManyToOne => Customer)
    rate (float)
```

`getJobRate()` could be implemented on `Customer` as you described:

```
public function getJobRate(Job $job) {

    foreach($this->jobRates as $jobRate) {
        if($jobRate->getJob()->getId() === $job->getId())
            return $jobRate->getRate();
    }

    return $job->getDefaultRate();
}
```

This leaves you open to the possibility of adding more information to the `CustomerJobRate` e.g., discount.